# How to tie weights between transposed layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have try to tied weights in tensorflow 2.0 keras, with below code. but it shows this errors? does anyone know how to write tied weights dense layer ?

```
tf.random.set_seed(0)
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # This returns a tensor
    inputs = Input(shape=(784,))

# a layer instance is callable on a tensor, and returns a tensor
    layer_1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')
    layer_1_output = layer_1(inputs)
    layer_2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')
    layer_2_output = layer_2(layer_1_output)
    weights = tf.transpose(layer_1.weights[0]).numpy()
    print(weights.shape)
    transpose_layer = Dense(
        784, activation='relu')
    transpose_layer_output = transpose_layer(layer_2_output)
    transpose_layer.set_weights(weights)
    predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(transpose_layer)

    # This creates a model that includes
    # the Input layer and three Dense layers
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    # print(model.weights)
model.summary()
```

Errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "practice_2.py", line 62, in <module>
transpose_layer.set_weights(weights)
File "/Users/cheesiang_leow/.virtualenvs/tensorflow-2.0/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 934, in set_weights
str(weights)[:50] + '...')
ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "dense_2" with a  weight 
list of length 64, but the layer was expecting 2 weights. Provided weights: 
[[-0.03499636  0.0214913   0.04076344 ... -0.06531...
```

Comment: [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5060) might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took much of my time to figure out, but I think this is the way of Tied Weights by subclassing Keras Dense layer.

```
class TiedLayer(Dense):
    def __init__(self, layer_sizes, l2_normalize=False, dropout=0.0, *args, **kwargs):
        self.layer_sizes = layer_sizes
        self.l2_normalize = l2_normalize
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.kernels = []
        self.biases = []
        self.biases2 = []
        self.uses_learning_phase = True
        self.activation = kwargs['activation']
        if self.activation == "leaky_relu":
            self.activation = kwargs.pop('activation')
            self.activation = LeakyReLU()
            print(self.activation)
        super().__init__(units=1, *args, **kwargs)  # 'units' not used

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) >= 2
        input_dim = int(input_shape[-1])

        self.input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2, axes={-1: input_dim})
        # print(input_dim)
        for i in range(len(self.layer_sizes)):

            self.kernels.append(
                self.add_weight(
                    shape=(
                        input_dim,
                        self.layer_sizes[i]),
                    initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                    name='ae_kernel_{}'.format(i),
                    regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                    constraint=self.kernel_constraint))

            if self.use_bias:
                self.biases.append(
                    self.add_weight(
                        shape=(
                            self.layer_sizes[i],
                        ),
                        initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                        name='ae_bias_{}'.format(i),
                        regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
                        constraint=self.bias_constraint))
            input_dim = self.layer_sizes[i]

        if self.use_bias:
            for n, i in enumerate(range(len(self.layer_sizes)-2, -1, -1)):
                self.biases2.append(
                    self.add_weight(
                        shape=(
                            self.layer_sizes[i],
                        ),
                        initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                        name='ae_bias2_{}'.format(n),
                        regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
                        constraint=self.bias_constraint))
            self.biases2.append(self.add_weight(
                shape=(
                    int(input_shape[-1]),
                ),
                initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                name='ae_bias2_{}'.format(len(self.layer_sizes)),
                regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
                constraint=self.bias_constraint))

        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.decode(self.encode(inputs))

    def _apply_dropout(self, inputs):
        dropped = K.backend.dropout(inputs, self.dropout)
        return K.backend.in_train_phase(dropped, inputs)

    def encode(self, inputs):
        latent = inputs
        for i in range(len(self.layer_sizes)):
            if self.dropout > 0:
                latent = self._apply_dropout(latent)
            print(self.kernels[i])
            latent = K.backend.dot(latent, self.kernels[i])
            if self.use_bias:
                print(self.biases[i])
                latent = K.backend.bias_add(latent, self.biases[i])
            if self.activation is not None:
                latent = self.activation(latent)
        if self.l2_normalize:
            latent = latent / K.backend.l2_normalize(latent, axis=-1)
        return latent

    def decode(self, latent):
        recon = latent
        for i in range(len(self.layer_sizes)):
            if self.dropout > 0:
                recon = self._apply_dropout(recon)
            print(self.kernels[len(self.layer_sizes) - i - 1])
            recon = K.backend.dot(recon, K.backend.transpose(
                self.kernels[len(self.layer_sizes) - i - 1]))
            if self.use_bias:
                print(self.biases2[i])
                recon = K.backend.bias_add(recon, self.biases2[i])
            if self.activation is not None:
                recon = self.activation(recon)
        return recon

    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'layer_sizes': self.layer_sizes
        }
        base_config = super().get_config()
        base_config.pop('units', None)
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        return cls(**config)
```

Hope it can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

For embedding layers:
(I'm using tensorflow 2.9.1)

```
class EmbeddingTransposed(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, tied_to: tf.keras.layers.Embedding = None, activation: str = None, **kwargs):
        super(EmbeddingTransposed, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tied_to = tied_to
        self.activation = tf.keras.activations.get(activation)


    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.custom_weights = self.tied_to.weights[0]
        self.built = True


    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0], tf.keras.backend.int_shape(self.tied_to.weights[0])[0]


    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        output = tf.keras.backend.dot(inputs, tf.keras.backend.transpose(self.custom_weights))
        if self.activation is not None:
            output = self.activation(output)
        return output


    def get_config(self):
        config = {"activation": tf.keras.activations.serialize(self.activation)}
        base_config = super(EmbeddingTransposed, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets first see the model architecture and the model parameters (without tying the weights)

[image]

The blue arrows represent the bias. So a neuron with n inputs will have n+1 weights.

Now you want to tie the weights of `transpose_layer` with `layer_1`. You took the weight of `layers_1` transposed it to `64*784` and setting it into `transpose_layers` but there are couple of issues

`weight[0]` will give the weights and `weight[1]` will give the bias of the dense layer. So you are good there. But `set_weights` will need a list of weights. In case of `Dense` layers it will need a list of two np arrays first list being the weight of size (64*784) and second list being a np array of size 784 for bias. So how will get 784 bias values then ?

**Solutions:**

1. One good option is to disable bias by setting `use_bias=False`
2. Leave the bias values as they are. (read the bias values via `weight[1]` and pass them back in `set_weights`)
3. Just set bias to some small random values (very very bad idea)

**Code using solution 1:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

    inputs = Input(shape=(784,))

    layer_1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')
    layer_1_output = layer_1(inputs)

    layer_2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')
    layer_2_output = layer_2(layer_1_output)

    transpose_layer = Dense(784, activation='relu', use_bias=False)
    transpose_layer_output = transpose_layer(layer_2_output)

    transpose_layer.set_weights([layer_1.get_weights()[0].T])

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=transpose_layer_output)
    model.compile('adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

    model.summary()
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_36 (InputLayer)        (None, 784)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_155 (Dense)            (None, 64)                50240     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_156 (Dense)            (None, 64)                4160      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_157 (Dense)            (None, 784)               50176     
=================================================================
Total params: 104,576
Trainable params: 104,576
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**Note:** You can see that with `use_bias=False` in `transpose_layer` resulted in `784*64 = 50176` weight as opposed to `50960` weights as show in figure (with bias)

Comment: sorry for late reply. @mujjiga, However this i think might be not the way to tied the weights. I think this is the way of intializing the weights with previous layers.
I might figured out how to tied the weights.

Comment: Sorry, but this code does not tie weights during training. It only copies the weights *once* before training. After that, there are still two different trainable variables, which will be trained separately.